# Я не могу указать в target platform android.Android SDK,и остальное установил.Так в чем проблема?

Tags: c#, xamarin

Я не могу указать в target platform android.Android SDK,и остальное установил.Так в чем проблема? 
[image: Все установлено]
[image: Почему не могу выбрать target platform: android]

Answer (score 0):

Это делается в созданном проекте. Зайдите в настройки проекта Андроид. Найдете там минимальную и максимальную версию.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]